# «И(,) хлебнув столицы до дна, ты шагнула, Женька, с окна...» Нужна ли запятая после И?

Tags: пунктуация

> И хлебнув столицы до дна,
>
> Ты шагнула, Женька, с окна,
>
> И погасли в синих глазах
>
> Ясные огни, е-е-е-е.

Нужна ли ещё одна запятая, а именно запятая после слова «и» в первой строке?

Я сомневаюсь в наличии или отсутствии запятой, потому что там присутствует деепричастный оборот. И я не знаю, как определить его границы. Входит ли это самое И в состав деепричастного оборота?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, свои соображения, почему вам кажется, что запятая нужна или, наоборот, не нужна. Это деепричастный оборот, обычно они обособляются, но интонационно и в стихотворении могут и нет - ещё это зависит от того, к чему логически относится "и".

Comment: @shabunc: it lacks research but otherwise it looks like a good question to me and the references are not "easily available". mind if I reopen it?

Comment: @Quassnoi I never mind and always trust your opinion on issue.

Comment: Странно.  Почему я сомневаюсь в наличии или отсутствии запятой? Да потому, что там присутствует деепричастный оборот. И я не знаю, как определить его границы. Входит ли это самое И в состав деепричастного оборота? Но вообще-то это текст известной песни группы "Божья Коровка", т. е. споры тут бесполезны. Если вы хорошо знаете данный текст, Вы бы без труда помогли мне. Ну а если не знаете, если песня Вам совершенно незнакома — возможно, стоит воздержаться от комментариев о том, какой вопрос плохой. (It lacks research и т. п.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on what sense the *и* is used in.

If it means "and", then you need the comma (as is common with adjectival adverb phrases)

If it means "even", as in the examples below, then you don't need the comma. This is the case if you can replace *и* with *даже* or *даже и*.

Here are some examples of the conjunction *и* used in the sense of "even":

> Эту лиловую синеву, сквозящую в ветвях и листве, я и умирая вспомню… *[Валерий Володин. Повесть временных лет // «Волга», 2011]*

> И надо сказать, что и став императором, он осуществлял высочайшее покровительство всех историко-культурных и художественных институтов // *[Юлия Кудрина. «Распространение искусства есть дело государственной важности» // «Знание - сила», 2010]*

> По-видимому, это происходит потому, что и будучи введенной, третья сфера, предполагающая статический срез чистого смысла, не понимается в учитывающей ее аналитике как обладающая своей отдельной, самостоятельной смысловой самоценностью // *[Л. А. Гоготишвили. «Эйдетический язык» (реконструкция и интерпретация радикальной феноменологической новации А. Ф. Лосева) (2006)]*

In your excerpt, it's most probable that the *и* is being used with the former meaning, and you *do* need the comma.

But I can't completely rule out the latter meaning either. *(Даже) и хлебнув столицы до дна, ты шагнула, Женька, с окна* is kind of making sense to me — even though it's less probable.

Whether you need the comma or not boils down to the intended meaning of the phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Если было был так

> И, хлебнув столицы до дна,
>
> Ты шагнула, Женька,...

то можно было бы рассматривать оборот как уточнение и попробовать его убрать без нарушения смысла.
И получилось бы

> И ты шагнула, Женька,...

будто до нее кто-то уже такое сделал - смысл меняется.

Т.о. запятая здесь не нужна по смыслу и *И* является частью оборота.

P.S.
Предположение @Quassnoi о возможном варианте

> (Даже) и хлебнув столицы до дна,

> Ты шагнула, Женька, с окна

ошибочно, т.к. тогда первые две строки не сочетаются по смыслу, т.к. у *хлебнув столицы до дна* явная негативная коннотация.

Сравните смысл и логику: "совершить самоубийство, несмотря на **негативный** жизненный опыт" и "совершить самоубийство, несмотря на **позитивный** жизненный опыт".